# tkinter set Entry textvariable while having multiple GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

can anyone explain why it is not possible to use tk.Entry textvariable if you have multiple GUIs in Python?

Imagine this:

I have a program that opens a GUI where a User can choose a file and that file with the filepath is getting set as the textvariable. This variable is getting set 100% correctly because if I tell my program to execute this GUI part then my Entry gets filled with the textvariable that the user chooses.

NOW why does it not work if I have a GUI that calls this (above) GUI with a button?

The values are not changed it's just 1 more GUI that gets called before the one.

SO this needs to be a problem with Python in general I think - does anyone know a workaround?

Some code:

```
# Data
catalog_file_path = StringVar()

# Functions
def getCatalogPath():
    global catalog_file
    catalog_file = filedialog.askopenfile(
        mode='r', filetypes=[("Text files", "*.txt")])
    catalog_file_path.set(catalog_file.name)
    catalog_file.reconfigure(encoding='cp1252')
    !! if I print here the value is correct !! 
    return catalog_file


# File-Path Textbox
textBox_catalog_file_path = Entry(
    gui, textvariable=catalog_file_path, width=50)
textBox_catalog_file_path.config(font=guiFont)
textBox_catalog_file_path.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=15)
```

Notice that the code does generally work but the textvariable just doesn't get shown at least if there is a GUI calling the Gui - so multiple GUIs basically. Is there something like a refresh element Funktion or something?

Thanks, Faded.

Comment: try `StringVar(master=window)` where `window` is the other window, also don't use multiple instances of `Tk()` for other windows You could use `Toplevel()`

Comment: what window do u want me to put there? stringvar is in the same gui that it needs to be its just that python seems not to refresh the textvariable field if its not the only GUI

Comment: do You know what a GUI is? it is graphical user interface and it can consist of multiple windows, so here: `StringVar(master=window)` put the window where the widget that is using that `StringVar()` is located, also using entries You can use: `entry_instance.get()` (which is probably better in this case)

Comment: @Matiiss okay dude you are the man. the master = window thing really worked, which I did not expect tbh. Thanks